# Old react state is persisting when calling a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How come the `updateUser()` function is getting the old users even though I have used useCallback and put `users` in the dependency

Ideally the output when clicking update button should be like this

```
{"id":1,"name":"John","age":10,"gender":"male"}

{"id":2,"name":"Stacy","age":15,"gender":"male"}

{"id":3,"name":"Kevin","age":30,"gender":"male"}

{"id":4,"name":"Jessi","age":13,"gender":"male"}
```

but in current output only the last user is getting updated

```
{"id":1,"name":"John","age":10}

{"id":2,"name":"Stacy","age":15}

{"id":3,"name":"Kevin","age":30}

{"id":4,"name":"Jessi","age":13,"gender":"male"}
```

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "John", age: 10 },
    { id: 2, name: "Stacy", age: 15 },
    { id: 3, name: "Kevin", age: 30 },
    { id: 4, name: "Jessi", age: 13 }
  ];
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(data);

  const updateUser = useCallback(
    (newUser) => {
      console.log(users);
      const newState = users.map((user) =>
        user.id === newUser.id ? newUser : user
      );
      setUsers(newState);
    },
    [users]
  );

  const startUpdate = () => {
    for (const user of users) {
      updateUser({ ...user, gender: "male" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {users.map((user) => {
        return <p key={user.id}>{JSON.stringify(user)}</p>;
      })}

      <button onClick={startUpdate}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are calling updateUser multiple times in a row. Each time it is called, you're setting the state. Changes to state are not instant in react. So each sequential call will overwrite the previous one and you'll end up with just the final entry being updated.

In your example, the best way to do it would be in your `startUpdate` function you can manipulate the dataset, store it in a separate variable and then update the state by passing the entire object.

Answer (score 2):

`setUsers(newState)` is not executed immediately. It works in an async way. This means that everytime you call `updateUser` from your for loop, the `users` state won't be updated yet and every call will get to see the original state, as it was at the beginning of the for loop.

So the last call to `setUsers(newState)` will override the state with the first original state and the updated last user.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is that you are calling `useCallback` inside a loop.

From the [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#caveats):

> `useCallback` is a Hook, so you can only call it **at the top level of your component** or your own Hooks. You can’t call it inside loops or conditions. If you need that, [extract a new component and move the state into it](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#i-need-to-call-usememo-for-each-list-item-in-a-loop-but-its-not-allowed).

But if you just want to update the properties of each user, you can try this instead:

```
// new props that needs to be added to each user
const newProps = { gender: "male" }

const updateUser = useCallback((props) => {
  console.log(users);
  const newState = users.map((user) => {
    return { ...user, ...props }
  });
  setUsers(newState);
}, [users]);
```

And then call the `updateUser` function on the click event:

```
<button onClick={() => updateUser(newProps)}>update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to set the state by using callBack

```
const updateUser = useCallback(
    (newUser) => {
      console.log(users);
      // const newState = users.map((user) =>
      //   user.id === newUser.id ? newUser : user
      // );
      setUsers((prevUser)=> (prevUser.map((user) =>
      user.id === newUser.id ? newUser : user
    )));
    },
    [users]
  );
```